# Renewing my intention on knowledge shared online

Tags: sadaqah, niyyah

Assalamu Alaikum,

I do software development and I like to share the knowledge with people to help them learn and unblock them when they are blocked. In this logic, I have recorded multiple YouTube videos sharing my knowledge and teaching people how to code and how to develop software programs.

When I shared the videos, my intention, wa Allahu aalam, was to share knowledge and to help people.

My questions are as follows:

1. Are those videos teaching people software considered as sadaqah Jarya?
2. Should I renew my intention for those videos to make it intended as a sadaqah?

Jazakum Allahu khairan,
Assalamu Alaikum,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR

> Are those videos teaching people software considered as Sadaqah Jarya?

Yes.
As Ali bin Abi Talib said:

> زكوة العلم نشره

> Should I renew my intention for those videos to make it intended as a sadaqah?
> Would be better if you do this.

---

- Creating educational videos with the intention of sharing knowledge and helping others can indeed be considered as Sadaqah Jariyah. Sadaqah Jariyah refers to continuous charity that benefits others even after the giver has passed away.
- It is commendable to renew your intention periodically to ensure that your actions align with your intentions of seeking the pleasure of Allah. By consciously intending your efforts as Sadaqah, you not only benefit others but also earn rewards for your intentions and actions.